שבועה to not be מתיר נדר - is it חל?
Someone who made a שבועה saying that he will never be מתיר a נדר or a שבועה, is this חל (valid)?
Question 2- what if this would indirectly cause him to transgress an עבירה?

Can you elaborate on the second point? Why would it cause an aveira?

@shmosel let’s say they made a neder not to put on teffilin (which I believe works) and a שבועה to not be מתיר נדר

@shmosel and a further case would be if he made a neder from tefillin al tnai that he does an עבירה דרבנן. So he must do the דרבנן in order to be able to put on tefillin, unless he’s מתיר נדר.

I don't think that would make any difference. But I'm curious what your source is that you should violate a d'rabbanan in the second case.

In any case, shulchan aruch (Y"D 229:7) discusses a case where you make a vow and then swear not to annul it, and the solution is to annul the second vow and then annul the first. But in that case there's no blanket vow against annulment, whereas your case would seem to be more of a problem. But Biur HaGra seems to infer that there's no such thing as an irreversible private vow.

@shmosel my source is logic, if you have a choice between a דאורייתא and דרבנן do the דאורייתא (pretty sure there are many such statements in Gemara)

I'm sure there are many statements about prioritizing d'oraisa over d'rabbanan, but it's quite a leap from there to sanctioning halachic blackmail.
